# Error in export image from GEE to drive

Tags: google-earth-engine

i'm trying to export image from GEE to my drive and I have gotten this error messege:
Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Byte and Float64.

I have read here that it may have to do with the bands, but the thing is that I don't really need all the bands, I want to download it in RGB .

this is the code I have :

```js
// Load a Landsat 8 -atmospheric corrected
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR') 
//surface reflectance
    .filterBounds(table)
    .filterDate('2015-03-01', '2018-03-31');

// Get the number of images.
var count = collection.size();
print('Count: ', count);


// make a composite (mean image) of the images 
var meanImage = collection.mean().clip(table);
print(meanImage,'mean image');

//make image for mesopotamia only
//var mesopotamia=meanImage.clip(table);

//visualization
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

Map.addLayer(meanImage,visParams,'Landset8');
//Map.addLayer(mesopotamia,visParams,'Mesopotamia');


var toexport = meanImage.visualize(visParams).addBands(meanImage)

  // Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: toexport,
  description: 'MesopotamiaLandset8',
  scale:30,
  maxPixels:201406799,
  region: table
});
```

Comment: Try this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288526/exporting-data-with-different-data-types-in-google-earth-engine-how-to-make-dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line may be causing the error

```
var toexport = meanImage.visualize(visParams).addBands(meanImage)
```

The `.visualize(visParams)` will give you an RGB image that can be easily displayed. It will be formatted to 8 bit (i.e. the radiometric resolution of essentially all screens, monitors, etc.).

However the `.addBands(meanImage)` method then appends all the bands in meanImage, which should be int16 (Landsat 8 radiometric resolution).

It is not clear why you got a Byte and Float64 error message (I did not) but the following should work..

```
var toexport = meanImage.visualize(visParams)
```